# Is it possible to change properties on a sub item in a DataTemplate using triggers from the containing control?

Tags: wpf, listview, triggers, datatemplate

I want to change the background colour of the rectangle in the IsMouseOver trigger, is this possible?

```
<Window>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StackListViewItemTemplate">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" >
                        <Rectangle.Fill>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FF000000" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="{Binding Path=Events.Colour}" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Rectangle.Fill>
                    </Rectangle>
                    <TextBlock FontSize="18pt" Grid.RowSpan="2" Text="{Binding Path=Events.Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"  />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid >
        <ListView ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource StackListViewItemTemplate}">
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <!-- Here I want to set the background colour of the Rectangle in the DataTemplate -->
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <!-- Same here -->
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>

                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

**Edit:**

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
```

Is there a way to bind the Property value of the setter to child controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working using a datatrigger in the template

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="listItemTemplate" DataType="ListViewItem">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Name="myRectangle" RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" >
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" />
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListViewItem}}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="myRectangle" Property="Fill" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Green" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do something like this:

[XAML Tutorial - Changing the Text Color on Mouse Over](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xaml-tutorial-changing-text-color-on-mouse-over)

...but with a rectangle of course.

Comment: The problem is with the ListView and the DataTemplate. The trigger works, but it sets the background of the ListViewItem which wraps the Grid and Rectangle. I want to change the bacground of just the rectangle.